# WPF+PRISM on windows 8 region.active crash

Tags: wpf, windows-8, prism

I'm working om project base on WPF .net 4 with Prism 4.0, 
after I upgrade my machine from windows 7 to windows 8, 
the project crash when reach the point of active view

```
object view = s.GetView(viewName);

if (view != null)
{
  theRegion = (Region)s;
  s.Activate(view);
}
```

The exception occur in the line  s.Activate(view)
the exception details is"Value cannot be null.Parameter name: view"

This is strange because I check that the view isn't null.
on windows 7 it's working

any advice ?

Thanks

Yair

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm, that seems like a threading issue to me.  Is there another piece of code that could be potentially running in parallel and also getting the view, and modifying it between the time the if statement and your Activate method is called?

If so, the [double-check locking pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) would fix your problem.

```
if (view != null) 
{ 
    lock (myLock)    // myLock is just a static object
    {
        if (view != null) 
        { 
            theRegion = (Region)s;
            s.Activate(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you would also need to lock myLock in other places where you are modifying your view.

Comment: OK 
I debug the problem with source code of Prism and this what I found,

This is the flow When I activate view:

IsActive >> OnItemMetadataChanged >> NotifyAdd >> OnCollectionChanged >>  ActiveViews_CollectionChanged 

The ActiveViews_CollectionChanged function called twice,
first for the new view with Notify...Add 

and the second for the old view with Notify...Reove 
after the first call reach the line this.Region.Deactivate(this.hostControl.SelectedItem);

The second call reach the line this.hostControl.SelectedItem = null;
and thats what make null exception later, any advice ?